# Vectorising an R function

Tags: r, vectorization

I have the following function

```
f <- function(x){sum(g(x - X))}
```

where

```
X - n-dimensional vector with some data
g is some vecrtorized function
```

How can I vectorize the function `f` so that it could take n-dimensional input and yield n-dimensional output?

I was trying the following

```
rowSums(sapply(x, "-", X))
```

The problem with this approach is that it does not cover the case of one-dimensional `x`. Is it possible to cover both cases? For example let

```
x <- c(1,2,3)
X <- c(6,9,1)
g <- function(x){x^2}
```

If I use `sapply`-based code I get the correct answer (n-dimensional vector)

```
rowSums(sapply(x, "-", X))
[1] -12 -21   3
```

But if I set `x=1` and run the same code, I get the wrong answer (n-dimensional vector instead of scalar)

```
rowSums(sapply(x, "-", X))
[1] -5 -8  0
```

This is not surprising, since `rowSums` applied to the column-vector gives the column vector. What I need in case of one-dimensional `x`, however is to apply `sum`. Is there an elegant way to do so without using the `if` conditional on dimensions?

Comment: You should probably add example input/output for both cases you talk about.

Comment: `sapply` is not really vectorising, it's just a for loop in disguise. It seems to me that you want `outer` perhaps, but as Dason says the intended output would help.

Comment: Your terminology is confusing to me. You have only shown `x` and `X` that are one-dimensional. And I think "vector" means one-dimensional. Are you talking about arrays (higher dimensions) or vectors with lengths greater than 1?

Comment: I meant vector to be n-dimensional, like an element of `R^n` and a scalar to be one-dimensional, like an element of `R`. That is I was talking about vector length when referred to dimensions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you have two examples, I've named them `f` and `h`:

```
X <- c(6,9,1)

g <- function(x){x^2}
f <- function(x){sapply(x,function(x)sum(g(x - X)))}

f(1) 
# [1] 89
f(1:3)
# [1] 89 66 49

h <- function(x){colSums(sapply(x,function(x) x-X))}
h(1)
# [1] -13
h(1:3)
# [1] -13 -10  -7
```

It looked like `colSums` was what you were looking for there.